# How do I find a set of unit vectors with a given angle between each other?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, chemistry

I am coming from a biology/chemistry background and trying to make some math connections.

How would I go about solving for $n$ unit vectors (same magnitude) which are all equally spaced from each-other in a given space? Such that the angle between all $n$ vectors is maximized?

For example, say I wanted to find $4$ unit vectors which have equal angle from each-other in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

I know the angle here would be $\approx 109.5$ degrees per the bond angle of a tetrahedron (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_molecular_geometry) and understand a bit about the math involved in this case (vectors are the vertices on a cube centered at 0,0,0). But would someone be able to guide me toward how this can be generalized?

If anyone could also point me to relevant topics and sources, that would be great.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's no such thing as distance between two vectors. And it's not clear what you mean by maximized angle between them: do you mean that you want the angle between each pair of vectors to be the same and want it maximal?

Comment: I guess that he means to maximize the angle between any two vectors. More precisely, $\max \ \alpha$ such that $\widehat{v_i,v_j} \geq \alpha$, $i\neq j$.

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have been more clear. All angles between all vectors are the same and maximum, which I suppose they must be to all be the same. I was thinking distance in terms of the C-H bonds the vectors would represent in my example. Thanks!

Comment: If you want **all** angles the same, you'll need $n - 1$ dimensions for $n$ vectors.

Answer (score 3):

If you want all angles between 'adjacent' vectors to be the same and also maximized, it turns out that the number of vectors must be 2,3,4,6,8,12,or 20 (where two vectors are adjacent if there are no other vectors strictly closer to either). The vectors will end up representing the vertices of a platonic solid (like the tetrahedron you mentioned), except in the cases for 2 and 3.

In the slightly more general case where you just want the maximum angle between any pair of 'adjacent' vectors to be minimized, I'm fairly certain that this is not usually solvable. You can approximate solutions, though.

One resource I've found is here: (http://neilsloane.com/packings/index.html#I). You'll find a chart that gives the maximal angle for n points, up to 130 points in 3 dimensions. The first line in the chart shows that the maximal angle for 4 points is approximately 109.5 degrees, as you've already found.

Comment: I expect that there are configurations in which all angles between "adjacent" vectors are equal for numbers of vectors that aren't in your list. The configurations will be less symmetric and may be harder to find.

Comment: That is an interesting resource thank you. Is it possible to find an n-polytope in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, centered on the origin with distance 1, similar to the [tetrahedron example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_molecular_geometry#/media/File:Tetrahedral_angle_calculation.svg)? And would those vertices be vectors that are the same angle from eachother? Then solve $\theta$? I am more interested in getting the unit vectors that are all equal angles from each-other.